# Ember-cli Component show records to component template

Tags: ember.js

test-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
        store: Ember.inject.service(),
    showLang: Ember.on('init', function() {
      var store = this.get('store');
      return store.findAll('language');
    }),
});
```

I checked with console and yes they show 
XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/languages". 
So backend recognize my test-component function.

Now in test-component.hbs I have

```
{{#each showLang as |lang| }}
<li><a href="/all/language/{{lang.url}}">{{lang.title}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

The result was empty. How can I do so data could show up in test-component.hbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you should do it in route and pass data as model to component, but if you really want to do this in component you can do so:

test-component.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  showLang: Ember.on('init', function() {
    this.get('store').findAll('language').then(languages => this.set('languages', languages));
  })
});
```

test-component.hbs:

```
{{#each languages as |lang| }}
  <li><a href="/all/language/{{lang.url}}">{{lang.title}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: .on syntax is discouraged due to lack of _super() and the fact you can't guarantee the order of execution if several functions are bound to the same framework hook. i would say use the init hook directly and call a private function but even that would be wrong. this code belongs in didInsertElement

Comment: @ChristopherMilne This code definitelly does not belong in didInsertElement, it's about setting a property on your component which has nothing to do with the element being in the DOM or not.

Comment: @jcbvm That's interesting. I see the code as belonging in didInsertElement because it contains asynchronous operations that need to be resolved in the init hook, needlessly delaying the rendering of the component. Am I wrong?

Comment: Because it's async, it will not lock up the run loop. It will render the component and updating it when languages gets set (probably you wouldn't notice it if it's fast).

Comment: @jcbvm interesting. I guess I've never run into this because I've always done this sort of thing in the route.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an useful tips @Daniel
Yes I have my reasons to must you such this odd methods to take records